# PostAsync ignores content type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

I have following page

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Async="true" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BadgePunchClockLegacy._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        
    <script>
        var Interval = setInterval(FactoryTimer, 1000);
        function FactoryTimer() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            document.getElementById("FTimer").innerHTML = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideLabel() {
            document.getElementById('<%= LabelResult.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        }
        if ( <%=response_value ? "true": "false"%> ) {
            setTimeout("HideLabel();", 5000);
        }

    </script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: skyblue">
      <h2>Badge Punch Clock</h2>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 style="text-align: center" id="FTimer"></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container" >
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <h2><label for="barcode">Codice badge</label></h2>
                <asp:TextBox ID="BarcodeInput" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"
                    OnTextChanged="Post_Click"></asp:TextBox> 
                <br /><br />
                <h2><asp:Label id="LabelResult" runat="server" /></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And in code behind:

```
protected async void Post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = Settings.Default.ApiAddress + "/api/login";
            BadgeInputDataDto dto = GetLoginDto();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto));
            ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, byteContent);
            response_value = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            if (response_value)
            {
                OperationSuccessful(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                OperationFailed(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Problem is, I try to send content as JSON, but client.PostAsync causes internal server error. When I check content type, Content-Type header is x/www-form-urlencoded and sent content is this:

__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=LmnXD3B4JNCguOgFzIrYrQOfVH5L1sK4MBquAcQ%2F9IcSGmcKXOGWiL9J%2BBhR3DjiQoiNyYW%2FbJTCTu9Y8ptP7kMWIXYlc0Y3MdIHech%2B0Tw%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334&__EVENTVALIDATION=lrq1HypynQzNR7z%2FV5lmzsLZXDbD7MDvaI691kn2WqkkibmGGBfiln4lFMGY%2Bc0zrhVM1fyChxTNNZpdB%2FMG78ZStZu8sh3VGPUAiusCputelEYSM3qvvIwAM3sGmdNI&ctl00%24MainContent%24BarcodeInput=SUPERVISOR

which is not what serialized object is.

How to make PostAsync actually use json content from buffer?

Comment: Why not just use `StringContent`?

Comment: Also... yegods, **why** are you still using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: `<@Page Async="true"` <-- Doing this will not make your WebForms server-side event-handlers work: you need to use `RegisterAsyncTask`. You need to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: @Dai Some people are [unfortunately advocating for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801546).

Comment: @mason Ah yes, Albert - he's quite the character :)

Comment: @Dai unfortunately it needs to work on some legacy hardware, so WebForms are enforced. Also I checked RegisterAsyncTask and it seems to make it run on load without waiting for user input, which is not what is necessary or desired to do.

Comment: @rob_tokarski Right: that's my point: you **can't** use `async` APIs from within WebForms server-side event-handlers like `Button1_Click`, etc (which only respond to full-page `<form>` POST requests anyway). You'll need to move that code into an `*.ashx` generic-handler which you would invoke via `fetch`, otherwise you'll be SOL.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this syntax

```
...
var contentData = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentData);
    
var dto = GetLoginDto();    
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto) ;       
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

....
```

and maybe try to use Task instead of void

```
protected async Task Post_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
..... //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it returns same eror.

Comment: @rob_tokarski Can you post  what is  json  after JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto) ?

Comment: {"BarcodeInput":"SUPERVISOR","OperationTime":"2023-03-22T00:24:30.5375457+01:00"}

BarcodeInput is string and OperationTime is DateTime? (nullable)

Comment: @rob_tokarski Can you post  API code pls?